# Need to find all palindromes of a specific length

Tags: python, palindrome

Given a string, I need to find the index of all palindromes of a specific length within that sequence and then print that index next to the palindrome length.

For example, if I wanted palindromes that are 4 characters long:

```
seq = 'abbacdefggfhijkkjlmn'
```

the optimal readout would be:

```
[(0,4), (7,4), (13,4)]
```

I have written a function that does this, however I have a glitch in it. It returns the correct data set, but it returns it over and over again, as many times as the sequence length. For example, given the sequence above, it would return the data set 20 times:

```
def find_palindromes(seq,y):
L = len(seq)
res = []
for x in seq:
    x=0
    while x<= L-y:
        if seq[x:x+y] == reverse(seq[x:x+y]):
            res.append((x,y))
        x=x+1
return res
```

Any insight as to my glitch would be really appreciated. I know this may not be the most efficient way of doing things, but I'm incredibly new and just trying to get my feet wet.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: You're looping with a `for` loop over `x`, then re-assigning `x` and doing a while loop over it. You will probably get what you want if you remove the `for x in seq` line and then fix the indentation up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for-loop is starting at 0 every time, so you're effectively doing this as many times as there are characters in `seq`. The while loop should be enough by itself — all you need to do is iterate through the sequence once. So (as 2rs2ts's comment says) just remove the `for x in seq` line.

That's the really simple fix: the slightly more drastic one is to switch your while-loop to a `for x in range(0, L-y):` loop.

Also: everything in your code that isn't the function header should be indented, so Python knows that it's inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. That makes a lot of sense and it fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 1 line expression that should fit your need:

```
def find_palindromes(seq,y):
  return [(seq.index(seq[x:x+y]),y) for x in range(len(seq)-y) if seq[x:x+y] == seq[x:x+y][::-1]]
```